# Naïve Bayes Theorem for multiple features

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

I understand the basic principles for the naïve bayes classification with one feature:

$$
P(Class|feature) = (P(f|Class) * P(Class)) / P(f)
$$

We have a dataset that has the following attributes/features:

`day | outlook | temperature | humidity | wind | play`

- Day is just a number (sequence)
- Outlook can be [sunny | overcast | rain]
- Temperature can be [cool | mild | hot]
- Humidity can be [normal | high]
- Wind can be [strong | weak]
- Play is [yes | no]

Now, we have a new instance: `today = (sunny, cool, high, strong)` and we want to know if we can play outside. This is Bayes classification with multiple features, as you've recognized.

The image below is a slide from my course at uni, however I don't understand anything of it.

[image: Slide from my course]

Who can explain to work out the above formulas to me like I'm five, maybe with Python code? I'd like to understand how I can do naïve bayes classification for multiple features.

Comment: There is no naive Bayes theorem, there are naive Bayes algorithm and Bayes theorem. What exactly is unclear for you?

Comment: @Tim It's about the Bayes Theorem with multiple features, as the image shows. I'd like an explanation of the steps I should take to do that and maybe some code :)

Comment: Your image related to naive Bayes algorithm... what exactly is unclear for you in here? Have you seen https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/understanding-naive-bayes or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/difference-between-naive-bayes-multinomial-naive-bayes ?

Comment: @Tim I understand the algorithm for one feature ( `P(Class|feature) = P(feature|Class)*P(Class)/P(feature)`). However, when I get multiple features (for example outlook, wind and humidity) I get lost with the formula in the image I included. I just don't understand what to do, how to tackle this.

Comment: @Tim I added more detail to my question, do you think you could help me out with the question?

Comment: I would suggest researching "conditional independence" and make sure you grasp this concept. Once you understand it, the Naive Bayes will be much more clear.

Comment: I do understand conditional independence, I'm just really confused about the slide/image I included. I wasn't sure at all how to tackle the formula and what was meant.

Answer (score 5):

Naive Bayes algorithm assumes that your features are independent (hence we call it "naive", since it makes the naive assumption about independence, so we don't have to care about dependencies between them). What follows, we model

$$ \begin{align}
p(C_k, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) &\propto p(x_1 | C_k) \, p(x_2 | C_k) \dots p(x_n | C_k) \, p(C_k) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i|C_k) \, p(C_k)
\end{align} $$

This follow from the [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). So in your example `today = (sunny, cool, high, strong)`, you look at $p($`day = sunny` $|$ `play = yes` $)$, and $p($`outlook = cool` $|$ `play = yes` $)$, etc.

For more details see the great [Wikipedia article on naive Bayes algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), the [Understanding Naive Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/understanding-naive-bayes) thread on our site and the [A simple explanation of Naive Bayes Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification) thread on StackOverflow.com.

Comment: Let me check if I understand correctly: `P(Class)` multiplied by `P(feature 1|Class) x ... x ... P(feature n|Class)` for every feature?

Comment: @jbehrens94 exactly, see the links for details and examples

Comment: Thanks, Tim! I've got just one more question, in the image in my question, there's something about estimation, how does that work? Why and when would I do that?

Comment: @jbehrens94 see the links I provided. TLDR: naive Bayes algorithm uses empirical probabilities (observed fractions) and then classifies by choosing the class that has greatest a posteriori probability (that's the argmax part). As simple as that.