# Is there a tabular or graphical way to show the updating of a belief?

Tags: self-study, bayesian

In this table inspired by [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZGCoVF3YvM)

[image: table of librarians and farmers that are shy or not]

I can read off a conditional probability by dividing a cell value by the total in the row or column.

For example the probability of a person being shy given that they are a librarian is 4/10

Is it possible to construct a table or graphic to illustrate [the Super Bowl answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548933/in-bayes-theorem-why-do-we-say-given-that-when-out-of-is-more-understandable) that is

> the probability of the Kansas City Chiefs making the playoffs this
> season is about 72% and the probability of them winning Super Bowl LVI
> at the end of the season is about 5%, then (since they must make the
> playoffs to progress to the Super Bowl) you can say
>
> "the probability of the Kansas City Chiefs winning Super Bowl LVI
> given that they make the playoffs is about 7%"

Comment: Euler diagrams come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a graph of the distribution of displacement versus fuel efficiency for cars.

If you pick a random car then your believes about the fuel efficiency (mgp) would be the marginal distribution in the middle.

Say you do a measurement of the displacement and it is below 100, then now you can 'update' your believes about the possible fuel efficiency of the randomly picked car, and use the light green/yellow distribution.

[image: showcase]